# Want to check IF File.Exists to define StreamReader, to then searching for specific line

Tags: readline, streamreader, file-exists

I don't write code often and my knowledge is still low-level. I need help for something that I can't figure out

```
    public static void SearchScriptEnd()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Read Log", "Starting to find: Test Suite Ended");
        var text = "Test Suite Ended";
        
        if (File.Exists(ConfigController.Home + TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]))
        {
            StreamReader file = 
                new StreamReader(ConfigController.Home + TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]);
        }else{
            
            StreamReader file = 
                new StreamReader(TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]);
        }
        
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(text))
            {
                Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Read Log", "[Success] Script End String has been found");
                Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info, "Read Log", string.Format("Line number: '{0}'", counter));
                return;
            }
       
            counter++;
        }
        
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Failure, "Read Log", "[Missing] Anvil Script End String NOT found");
        file.Close();
    }
```

At first, the while was in both statement and was working well, but I want to use the While outside of that statement, but I'm getting The name 'file' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) and I don't know how to get the value of file out of my If statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the variable out of the if-scope. Try this:

```
    StreamReader file;
    if (File.Exists(ConfigController.Home + TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]))
    {
        file = new StreamReader(ConfigController.Home + TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]);
    }else{            
        file = new StreamReader(TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]);
    }
```

That way you have a value in file for sure. Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I thought I tried that, but I think I kept the             StreamReader file = new StreamReader(ConfigController.Home + TestSuite.Current.Parameters["LogPath"]); in the statement, that's why it failed.

Comment: @PascalD. Great. Please consider accepting the answer.